# Grouped bar chart, sample vs population in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a grouped bar chart where I compare the percentage distribution of people in regions in the population in comparison to the distribution in the sample.

The code looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(in_sample= c('yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 
                          'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no',
                          'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no' , 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 
                          'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 
                          'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no' , 'yes', 'no'),
             region = c('West','East', 'South', 'North', 'West', 'East',
                            'South', 'North', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West',
                            'East', 'South', 'East', 'East', 'East', 'East',
                            'North', 'East', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'East',
                            'North', 'North', 'East', 'South', 'West', 'West',
                            'West','West', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'West',
                            'West', 'West', 'West', 'West', 'North', 'North',
                            'North', 'North', 'South', 'North', 'East', 'North',
                            'North', 'North', 'South', 'North', 'North', 'North',
                            'South', 'South', 'South', 'South', 'North', 'North'))
```

Now, I have a solution that looks like this:

```
  ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = region, y = ..prop.., group = 1), stat = "count") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, .4, .05), labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~in_sample, labeller = labeller(in_sample = c("no" = "Population", "yes" = "Sample"))) +
  theme_bw()
```

But I would like the regions to be grouped next to each-other and fill the in_sample values, so that I would have the share of people living in the North in the full population next to the share of people living in the North in the sample.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the bars by *in_sample* and use `position_dodge()`. Is this what you want?

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = region, y = ..prop.., group = in_sample, fill = in_sample), 
           stat = "count", position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, .4, .05), labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"), labels = c("Population", "Sample"), name = "")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for.